# bad url never ending request curl php

Tags: php, curl, header

I have a curl set up like this:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
return $data;
}
```

When I call it with the following:

```
$html = file_get_contents_curl("https://training.sap.com/service-id/module.php/core/as_login.php?AuthId=sf-sp&ReturnTo=%2Fsuccessfactors-community%2Fpermission-check");
```

You can see that link has an authentication, and I do not want to spend time on it. I just want that curl session to die after maybe 3 seconds or x seconds, or determine before hand if it is going to be a never ending loop on the curl for one reason such a SSL or password requirement etc.

Comment: you set the timeout in the code to 400 seconds.

Comment: Use CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, consider also using CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS